# How to balance volume on Windows

Tags: windows-7, audio

I can't figure out how to get a good balance on the applications within windows so I can stop modifying volume settings every time I get on a Google Hangout, watch Netflix, Hulu, instant message, play Starcraft 2 or League of Legends.  I'm always adjusting volume and it's driving me nuts!

I have multiple volume controls...

- Windows
- Audio splitter (I can press a button to switch between speakers and a
  headset, it also has volume control)
- Headset
- Speakers

The max volume on applications is always different.  I'd like to turn all volumne settings on high and then just make adjustments in all of my software.  The problem with the Windows Volume Mixer is that when I adjust volume it's only temporary.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean when you adjust the windows volume, it is temporary? Are any applications automatically changing the level on the mixer?

Comment: On my system, if I increase the volume of every application to maximum, all sliders will then mirror the overall volume 'Speakers'

Comment: There are a few ways to do what you want, each ranging in complexity. With the more complex the solution, the  more control  you have. http://www.chevolume.com/ will probably do what you want, if you need more control, https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/ can help. Or if you want to control absolutely everything but with limited access to tutorials,http://sar.audio/ is for you. I would suggest chevolume for your uses though, it should be enough.